# Where to get guid for debugging the PhoneGap app?

Tags: android, cordova, guid

I just started with PhoneGap development and have my first sample android app running on emulator. So I was looking for the ways to debug the app in case I need to. I came accross http://debug.phonegap.com/, which asks to include the js file within the code to be able to debug it. But since I am new to PhoneGap, I can't seem to find the guid. Hour or so of googling didn't give me anything useful, so here's my question to you folks:

- What is guid?
- Where do I find the guid in my PhoneGap app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- What is guid?

Globally Unique IDentifier

- Where do I find the guid in my PhoneGap app?

You don't find it, you just create your own on that webpage.

Reference: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/mobile/9781449324773/appendix-i-leftovers-the-top-six-things-we-didn-t-cover/377